# Set some value by accessing internal element

Tags: jquery

Hi I need to change this value 0 with some dynamic value. How do I do that by accessing this html.

Here is my html, I need to replace this 0 or any value here with some dynamic value. How do I achieve this through jquery.

```
<span class="likeCount">
   <i class="fa thumbsSignIcons fa-thumbs-up"></i>
   0
</span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
you have two way for doing this

1) by using existing class
   $('.likeCount .value').html('some value'); 

or 

2) assign id (id='test') to span and use 
   $('#test').html('555');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztvk2ta1/3/

Comment: And what is `.value` referencing? Maybe you should post the updated HTML in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you amend your HTML so that you can wrap the `0` value in a `span` element, otherwise you will have to traverse the DOM to find the specific textNode to update which is a pain. Try this:

```
<span class="likeCount">
   <i class="fa thumbsSignIcons fa-thumbs-up"></i>
   <span class="value">0</span>
</span>
```

```js
$('.likeCount .value').text('100'); // update the value to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it without needing the extra span

```js
var textNodes = $(".likeCount")  
  .contents()  //lets us get the text nodes
  .each(function() {
      if( this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length ) { //look for a text node with next  
          this.nodeValue = 10  //set new text
          return false; //exit loop
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="likeCount">
   <i class="fa thumbsSignIcons fa-thumbs-up"></i>
   0
</span>
```

But if you can wrap it in a span, that solution would be a lot better.